# AJAX isn't triggering PHP script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going on here. I'll open a different browser to check if what I changed works, and maybe my other browser cached something, and it will work! But then I do it again and it doesn't seem to. I'm going crazy.

On my website, syllableapp.com, I created a MySQL database I could connect to. I made a PHP script that connects to it, adds a simple entry to it, and is done. It's called `register_email.php`, and it's available to access [here](http://syllableapp.com/test/register_email.php). Accessing it manually via that URL will add the entry. Its code is as follows:

```
<?php
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "table");

    if ($db->connect_error) {
        echo "Could not connect to database.";
        exit;
    }
    else {
        $db->query("INSERT INTO emails (email) VALUES ('weird')");
        echo 1;
    }
?>
```

If I check, it gets added.

However, I want it to be added from a form. I have an HTML file at http://syllableapp.com/test/index.html that looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Syllable - iPhone Speed Reader</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <img src="images/app-icon.png" alt="App icon">

            <h1>Syllable</h1>
            <p>Speed reading app for iPhone. Devour all your Instapaper and Pocket articles, and learn to read much faster in the process.</p>

            <form method="post" action="">
                <input type="email" class="email" placeholder="Email me when it's live">
                <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Send">
            </form>

            <a href="http://twitter.com/syllableapp"></a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So when the user submits the form, the JavaScript file I linked to at the top intercepts the submit button press, and calls an AJAX function to submit it to the PHP form. The jQuery for that looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
        var email = $.trim($('.email').val());
        var emailRegEx = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;


        if (email == "" || !emailRegEx.test(email)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).effect("shake", { times:2 }, 75);
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://syllableapp.com/test/register_email.php",
                data: { "message": "hi" },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("failure");
                }
            });

        }
    });
});
```

Which basically just checks if it's a valid email address, then if so, calls the PHP file.

However, every time I click submit, it says failure. Why on earth is this happening? Why can I access it directly, but it won't let me use AJAX?

Comment: Do you have any php logs?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but how do I get a hold of those?

Comment: Look for a file called error_log, have you tried adding an e.preventDefault() at the beginning of the anon click function?  And passing e to the function.

Comment: Take a look at this reference http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/error_log-defines-file-where-script-errors-logged/

Comment: is that correct ?  data: { "message": "hi" },

Comment: What happens if you don't pass `data` to your success? You usually don't get anything back directly from `post` requests, otherwise you would use `get`.

Comment: use `console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);` in your $.ajax error option right before `alert("failure");` and let us know what it says

Comment: @gibberish Changed. http://syllableapp.com/test/ It still shows failure.

Comment: dataType:Json is missing.... Add it

Comment: @djheru I did that and it doesn't seem to be logging anything. But if I alert `alert(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);` it just spits out `error` as the alert.

Comment: @AmitHorakeri Didn't do anything different.

Comment: Use Firebug or chrome developer tools on the network tab to see the http request/response when you submit the form. What status is the HTTP request returning to the ajax script.

Comment: Are you using www in the url when you visit the site?

Comment: What. Now it appears to be working in every browser but Firefox. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but in your AJAX block change the URL line to this:

```
url: "register_email.php",
```

Also, as a test,

(1) change your alert command in the AJAX success function to:

```
alert(data);
```

and (2) insert this line immediately following the `<?php` directive in the file "register_email.php":

```
die('Made it to here');
```

Comment: Okay, how about the die() message at the top of register_email.php?  That will show you whether your ajax is even communicating or not.

Comment: Unsure your response. The `die()` command stops the PHP script and echoes out the string provided; the `alert(data)` command should alert the string that was echoed out. Did you see an alert() with the message "Made it to here" ?  Note: the var data used in the alert because that is the var name you provided just above on the line: `success: function(data) {`

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1) You're form needs an action or else it's not proper HTML.  You can set it to a value like "#"

2) When you click the submit button, you want the form submitted using custom ajax, and not through the standard way.  Your ajax handler for the click event should be something like:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
//...
});
```

You have event.preventDefault in your code, but the event variable isn't being passed to the function.  And I think you want event.preventDefault called every time, not just in the case of input validation failure.

3) Instead of using alerts, try using console.log and monitoring your javascript console to see if you get any errors.  Add those errors to your question to help us with your issue.

Comment: I now get this error when I alert both the errors (in the process of changing to to console.log now) `parsererror SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Made`

Comment: Ah, I believe I had the "die" message still in there. One second.

Comment: What. Now it appears to be working in every browser but Firefox. Why?

Comment: @DougSmith Change '$('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {' to '$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(event) {'  you need to pass the event variable to the function